# Intellij inline creates extra object

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Suppose I have

```java
  void setup() {
    var call = new DirectTransactCall();
    call.setRequestId("3fa85f64-5711-4562-b3fc-2c963f61afa6");
    expected = call;
  }
```

and I ask Intellij 2023.2.2 to inline the call variable

```java
  void setup() {
    new DirectTransactCall().setRequestId("3fa85f64-5711-4562-b3fc-2c963f61afa6");
    expected = new DirectTransactCall();
  }
```

Where

```java
  @Override
  public void setRequestId(String id) {
    this.requestId = id;
  }
```

Why does the new code generate 2 objects instead of 1, and why is requestId not set for the object assigned to expected?

My assumption is that inlining a variable should not change the behaviour of the code.

**UPDATE**

I expect

```java
  void setup() {
    expected = new DirectTransactCall();
    expected.setRequestId("3fa85f64-5711-4562-b3fc-2c963f61afa6")
  }
```

The `DirectTransactCall` object referenced by the `expected` instance variable (which is not final) has the requestId correctly set, as before.

Comment: What else could it do here?

Comment: "My assumption is that inlining a variable should not change the behaviour of the code." Note that your expected result *does* also change the behaviour of the code (but in a less invasive way)

Comment: The order of operations changes, but the result is the same. This happens anyway as the JIT compiler can change the order of execution if it won't change the result

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what it's supposed to do. The solution here is simply to not inline the variable. I'm not sure what else you would expect.

Comment: pls see update.

Comment: Okay well that's simply not how it works. If you want a refactoring that does that, you'll have to write an IntelliJ plugin. And note that that would actually change what the code does.

Comment: I want to know what to expect so I don't shoot myself in the foot. The IDE should not inline the variable without warning me that it will completely change the behaviour. `The Inline Variable refactoring allows you to replace a redundant variable with its value`. But that is not what's happening, i.e. it doesn't work.

Comment: If you feel that's a bug, you should report it to JetBrains. There's nothing we can do about it.

Comment: Fair enough. However, I think its a fair question